# Ошибка SQLConnect: SQL_ERROR

Tags: c, linux, postgresql, odbc

Имеется такая функция:

```
SQLConnect(dbc, driver, SQL_NTS, user, SQL_NTS, pwd, SQL_NTS)
```

`driver` - это имя базы данных (как я понял оно хранится в файле `odbc.ini`), `user` - логин, `pwd` - пароль.

При попытке запуска программы выдаёт ошибку.

Структура `odbc.ini`:

```
[MYDB]
Driver = PostgreSQL
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = sql.log
Database = students
Servername = fpm2.ami.nstu.ru
Password =
Port = 5432
Protocol = 9.3
ReadOnly = No
RowVersioning = No
ShowSystemTablea = No
ShowOidColumn = No
FakeOidIndex = No
ConnSettings =
```

В моем случае `driver` - это и есть `MYDB`.

Кусок кода

```
HENV env; //тип идентификатора окружения
HDBC dbc; //тип идентификатора соеденения 
HSTMT stmt, stmt_t, stmt_r; //идентификатор оператора int query = 0; 
if (error(SQLAllocEnv(&env)) < 0) goto end_; 
if (error(SQLAllocConnect(env, &dbc)) < 0) goto end_; 
if(error(SQLConnect(dbc, driver, SQL_NTS, user, SQL_NTS, pwd, SQL_NTS))<0) goto end_;
```

Бд - postgresql, программа - С с использованием средств ODBC, операционная система - Linux.

**Обновление**

Ошибка `SQL_ERROR`. Т.е. означает, что ошибка где-то в самой функции. `(error(SQLConnect(dbc, driver, SQL_NTS, user, SQL_NTS, pwd, SQL_NTS))<0)`, где `error(RETCODE code)` обработка ошибок.

БД на postgresql, язык С с использованием средств odbc, операционная система - Linux

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе текст ошибки. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] сразу под текстом вопроса.

Comment: попробуйте получить номер и текст ошибки. как это сделать — подсказать сложно ввиду того, что вы не указали, где и в чём вы используете функцию `sqlconnect`.

Comment: кусок исходного кода — это, конечно, полезная информация, и её стоит внести в вопрос (а не в комментарий, где нет форматирования), но под «где и в чём» я подразумевал, в первую очередь, язык программироваиня и операционную систему.